# Resume - 1 employer job duties for multiple companies

Tags: resume, helping

I am updating my resume and currently am employed by company A. 
The owner of company A also owns company B, company C and company D.
My job duties are the same for all of them companies but I also have certain job duties that only apply to 1 or 2 of the companies. How do i list this on my resume?

Answer (score 7):

List them all under Company A - that is the organisation that will matter with background checks. You can list the other companies as related.

> Title
>
> Company A (dates)
>
> *Description of responsibilities and examples of skills*
>
> Additional work for Company B, Company C, and Company D as part of role